# Is it possible to stack order PBIs for a sprint in TFS?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to stack order the PBIs in the sprint view of TFS. I've been able to do this by modifying order fields in excel but would like the same functionality as the product backlog.

Is there a configuration file I need to modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no way to do this from the Sprint board. It uses the same order as the Product Backlog though. This makes sense from a Scrum perspective, since the Product Owner defines the order of the backlog and his domain is the Product Backlog.